# Difference in SHA256 between Delphi and Node.js

Tags: node.js, delphi, cryptography

I am generating a hash in Node.js

```
const sha256 = crypto.createHash('sha256');
const hash = sha256.update(password).digest('base64');
```

and for password '123abc' - i get '3RMKhJ17KeVUGwXS9/hqSs1PHsWYwclDh4P1a8Tw/4A='

then I do the same in delphi

```
Hash:= (TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(THashSHA2.GetHashString(Str, SHA256)));
```

and for password '123abc' - i get 'ZGQxMzBhODQ5ZDdiMjllNTU0MWIwNWQyZidmODZhNGFjZNGYwZmY4MA=='

**Why different? What I made wrong?**

Comment: From the [`THashSHA2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Hash.THashSHA2.GetHashString) documentation: "Creates a hash digest from the provided input value and returns the value of the created digest **as a hexadecimal String.**"

Comment: Thx Olivier! 
If I made in node.js - sha256.update(password).digest('hex')
and in delphi - THashSHA2.GetHashString(Str, SHA256);

I took the same answer

But If I want to decode in base64 - what I must doing in delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get with Delphi the same value as Node.js gives, you have to do like this:

```
   Hash := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(Str, SHA256));
```